# jQuery smooth scroll to anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mousewheel

I wrote a fairly simple smooth scrolling function using jQuery `mousewheel` extension, and having no former experience with `$.mousewheel` I ran into a problem.

Basically, once `south delta` is called, I call an `$.animate` function using `scrollTop` to a class of `.anchor`

**HTML** (simplified for question):

```
<div id="static-section" class="anchor"></div> <!-- width: 100%; height: 258px -->
<div id="alt-section" class="anchor"></div> <!-- width: 100%; height: 346px -->
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
        if( delta > 0 ) {
            console.log("North: " + delta);
        }

        else if( delta < 0 ) {
            console.log("South: " + delta);
            // ANIMATE TO ANCHOR FUNCTION
            $("html,body").animate({scrollTop: $(".anchor").offset().top}, "slow");
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

**So:** my problem is that it only animates to the *first* instance of `.anchor` (which would be `#static-section`) I have tried doing `scrollTop: $(".anchor").next().top` which obviously doesn't work, though no errors appear, it still only animates to the first instance. My first guess was to use a `for` loop, and I tried it, but it didn't work (no errors on that either.) I've never really had a use for `for` loops before, so I'm unsure as to whether or not what I did was correct. Any help would be much appreciated!

Note: jsFiddle (with the same code as my website) does not portray the same thing that I've already accomplished, so no live demo available. If you guys need it, I'll provide the URL upon request. :-)

Comment: Would using different class names for the 2 anchors - `.anchor-top` and `anchor-middle`- maybe, help?

Comment: @HenryFlorence Only if I could figure out how to iterate it each time `delta` goes south. Switching the target class is what I'm having trouble with...

Comment: it is possible to use the jQuery `.next()` method to iterate through the anchors selector, similar to: http://jsfiddle.net/mSVZ2/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will step through the `.anchor` tags:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $anchor = $('.anchor');
    $("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
        if( delta > 0 ) {
            console.log("North: " + delta);
        }

        else if( delta < 0 ) {
            console.log("South: " + delta);
            // ANIMATE TO ANCHOR FUNCTION
            $("html,body").animate({scrollTop: $anchor.offset().top}, "slow");
            $anchor = $anchor.next('.anchor');
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```